# an example of an union of infinitely many closed resulting failing to be closed

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for an example of an union of infinitely many closed resulting failing to be closed.

$$ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{k},1 \right]=(0,1]$$

As the set does not contain its limit point $0$, the set is not closed.

Is this sufficient explanation?

any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is.

Of course, *any* set $S$ (closed or not) in a metric space can be expressed as the union of closed subsets:$$S=\bigcup_{s\in S}\{s\}.$$